# "java.util.zip.ZipException: File too short to be a zip file" error while trying to install app

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile

I have been working on an app which I was able to succesfully install on a Samsung s8. Since yesterday I keep getting the following error while trying to install the app

```
4-01 14:16:41.602 13367-13367/? E/System: java.util.zip.ZipException: File too short to be a zip file: 0
   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:208)
   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:147)
   at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:161)
   at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:98)
   at libcore.io.ClassPathURLStreamHandler.<init>(ClassPathURLStreamHandler.java:47)
   at java.lang.VMClassLoader.createBootClassPathUrlHandlers(VMClassLoader.java:49)
   at java.lang.VMClassLoader.<clinit>(VMClassLoader.java:31)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
   at java.util.ResourceBundle$RBClassLoader.loadClass(ResourceBundle.java:452)
   at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control.newBundle(ResourceBundle.java:2569)
   at java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1438)
   at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1402)
   at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1356)
   at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1356)
   at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1298)
   at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:723)
   at java.util.logging.Level.<init>(Level.java:223)
   at java.util.logging.Level.<clinit>(Level.java:96)
   at java.util.logging.Logger.<clinit>(Logger.java:177)
   at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:393)
   at android.icu.util.TimeZone.<clinit>(TimeZone.java:92)
   at java.util.TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.java:712)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.commonInit(RuntimeInit.java:171)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:295)
```

I can install the app on a different S8 and other phones too. This error comes only on a particular device. Uninstalling the app and trying again does not help either. The app installs but crashes on opening.

Any leads would be hepful. Thank you

Comment: This doesn't look good. And it seems to be more related to the system itself than to your app. Can you find out which file it tries to open? And then compare it with the one on the other devices.

Comment: I see 
"E/System: Unable to open boot classpath entry: /system/framework/oem-services.jar" just before the logs in the question.
Does that give you any hints?

Comment: Try `adb shell ls -l /system/framework/oem-services.jar` to get more information about this file.

Comment: I get the result
ls: /system/framework/oem-services.jar: No such file or directory
Does that help? I'll look around what this file is used for etc in the meanwhile.

Comment: Ok now it does not work on the other s8 too.
It works on an older s7 but it gives me the same result "ls: /system/framework/oem-services.jar: No such file or directory "

Comment: Then I sadly don't have any other ideas, sorry.

Comment: no problem. Thank you.

Comment: I have similar errors, intermittently, when my app is trying to load the libsodium.jni.NaCl.sodium library.